# Unable to upgrade MySQL to version 8.0.34 under Windows 11

Tags: installation, windows-11, mysql

I tried to upgrade MySQL from version 8.0.32 to 8.034 under Windows 11 and I had a strange problem while doing that. Take a look at this picture:

[image]

As you can see, the `Next` button is not highlighted, and therefore I cannot press it. Does anyone know a way to make that button available?

Comment: Have you asked MySQL helpdesk?

Comment: If you unselect one of the products, and re-select it, does the Next button become active again?

Comment: Have you try to upgrade products one by one?

Comment: @Toto No. Isn't that a paid service?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, I had that idea, and, no, it did not work.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I tried to select `MySQL Server` only (that is, I unselected all the other options) and the `Next` was still unaveilable.

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85973

Comment: @spikey_richie It is not the same bug.

Comment: Is the installation running as Admin? The installing user must have the privilege "Log on to Microsoft Windows as a service".

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I did it as administrator.